# How to separate writes from reads to minimize effect of heavy read queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have write-heavy tables in my database. There is a need to run read-only queries by someone else. I have no idea about complexity and volume of their queries but I do know when they start doing it, writes become superslow. So separating writes from reads seems the way to go.

Is the replication an answer? What else may I try?

Comment: Replication is the best solution, if you can afford it.

Comment: You would probably be better off tuning the database and queries before you resort to replication to a read only database.

Comment: @TabAlleman What kind of replication will work the best?

Comment: @TheMadDBA Well, the other problem is that I don't even own the database. It's the third party web service I call and I know roughly what they do and what they use. So tuning could be done but I can't say I can make them do that. I am trying to gather my options before I suggest what they should do though. So thanks, I have now two things, tuning and replica.

Comment: You could start by adding `WITH(NOLOCK)` to your read queries - the risk is you may read dirty data but it should reduce the amount of blocking that would slow the writes down.

Comment: A data warehouse may be a better solution than replication.

Comment: @DStanley Sure. I'll poke to see how queries are run. If it's direct sql then this hint will work. Or maybe `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` too, right?

Comment: If your writes are slow because the reads are simply too resource hungry, then like others are saying, replication seems like a good idea.  But if your writes are slow because of lock contention, then another option would be turning on `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` for your database.  That way reads don't use locks anymore, yet remain transactionally consistent (unlike `with (nolock)`), but at the cost of consuming more tempdb.

Comment: @Schultz9999 That would work too - the main difference is that `WITH(NOLOCK)` is limited to one table while `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` impact all queries in that session.

Comment: @sstan `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is a database setting (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx). Hmm.. OK.

Comment: Depends on how close to "real time" you need the read operations to be.   If you absolutely need as near as possible to "real time" then transactional replication is the best solution.   If you can accept some latency, then other ETL methods could be fine.   Especially if you can do the ETL during periods when writes are not coming in so fast.

Comment: @DanBracuk That I am not familiar with at all. Not sure if it is easy for those guys to migrate if it requires migration.

Comment: @TabAlleman Don't need real time. Any chance to have a reference how to set that up?

Comment: How to set up replication?   That's too big a topic for a SO answer.   There are tutorials out there on it.   Same for setting ETLs to a Data warehouse, data mart, ODS.

Answer (score 1):

As anything related to performance "It depends".

In general you are overlooking because general speaking the isolation level ill take care of that kind of problem for you. You can hit the books to see how it works. In general it's not wise to meddling with it IF you don't know *exactly* what you are doing.

IF You ends to handle issues about it you can:

1) Replicate (but you need to delve in details about it).
Advantge is simplicity, disvantages: waste of servers disk and cpu.

2) Create stag tables.
This is s simple solution and suitable when you get lot of heavy writes on heavy read tables. Example. You got a webservice where users sometimes uploads large csv files and those data are persited on stag tables. That simple no indexed tables acts a buffer (or queue) to the raw data. Later in a "window of opportunity" that data is inserted in the real tables. It takes a disvantage of the uploaded data is not readly to be queried. Advantages are it easy to handle bad formated data and let only sanitized data go on your DB. Also very easy to implement You can create a SQL Service to to it after or before dayly full backup for example.

3) Fine tune isolation level query by query: Advantages are if you really know what to do the system ill shine disvantages are: hard to do the right tweeks, prone to let your system down in a hell of deadlocks, ghost & dirty reads and lost data. Also demands a lot of time to implement and maintain in the right way (you must keep an eye on that tunned queries to be sure).

**EDIT** about the **WITH(NOLOCK)** comment: Serious guys? it's deprecated since SQL 2000! It's the silver bullet for the Lazy and don't work well. Consider the scenario where you make a dirty read, processed some data and persisted more data related to that dirty one. Now a rollback undo the dirty one you now got a orphan row or worse data integrity hell. Don't use it anymore unless you still working with SQL Server 7. Study isloation level to know how bad and useless NOLOCK become (in the last 15 years!)

Comment: Take a deep breath, my friend, take a deep breath.

Comment: @Schultz9999 thanks, wish i got 1 dollar everytime someone advices about infalible and omnipresent nolock. Anyway chances are, due to the default isolation level, you writes ill not block your reads. Writes ill block more Writes

Answer (score 0):

For me the correct answer is replication, you can have a snapshot replication, have a different set of index in your insert database and another in your read. One focus on fast inserts and other in fast search.